How do you trigger a CSV export of iCloud Passwords from the command line?
Since macOS Monterey, you can export your iCloud passwords to CSV through the 'Export All Passwords' action in System Preferences > Passwords.
Is there a way to trigger this export from a script or command? (i.e. without having to go through the UI). I understand there will be human interaction required for authorizing the request, but that's ok, I just don't want to dig through the menus to trigger the action.

man security might help.

This is an old answer, but it may still be relevant.
